# Problemas formatação automatizada subseção Rmarkdown no R

Tags: r, rmarkdown

Preciso gerar um relatório que tem diversas seções e subseções, que dependendo do mês , podem aparecer ou não na base de dados

Para contornar o problema, criei um condicionante de aparição, um "sinal", que ao longo do meu código , quando é TRUE executa as seções e subseções e quando é FALSE, as omite da saida HTML.

O problema é que quando são plotagens de gráficos, as subseções estão sendo formatadas corretamente, mas quando são tabelas, usando kableExtra, a subseção não é formatada corretamente.

Gostaria de saber um método para que a subseção seja formatada corretamente, sem precisar colocá-la em um chunk separado, e entender por que isso acontece.

````
   ---
title: "Teste"
author: "TEste"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output: 
  rmdformats::material:
    highlight: kate
    self_contained: true
    thumbnails: true
    gallery: true
    fig_width: 11
    fig_height: 6
    df_print: kable
---




```{r inputs, echo=FALSE, results='hide', warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

sinal<-TRUE

```


```{r echo=FALSE, results='asis', eval= sinal}
cat("# Teste 01")
```



``` {r echo=FALSE, results = 'asis', eval = sinal }

cat("### Teste 02")


plot(mtcars$mpg)


```


``` {r echo=FALSE, results = 'asis', eval = sinal }

cat("### Teste 02")


plot(mtcars$mpg)


```



``` {r echo=FALSE, results = 'asis', eval = sinal }

cat("### Teste 03")

mtcars %>% kable(row.names = TRUE,format.args = list(decimal.mark = '.', big.mark = ",")) %>% 
          kable_styling(position = "center", full_width = FALSE,bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover","condensed"), font_size = 14) %>% row_spec(0,bold = T, color = 'white',background = 'black') 


```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `writeLines("### Teste 03")` ao invés de `cat("### Teste 03")`.

Funcionou para mim